# Regular Expression extractor in Jmeter not capturing value,

Tags: json, jmeter

I am writing a regular expression extractor for a dynamic value id from the response data as below

[image]

I wrote the expression like this
[image]

But this is not capturing the value. This id value is to be used in the next request.
If i use the template as $0$, then it captures the value as %202197

Please help to correct the mistake I have made

I tried with template $0$, and match number 0 and 1, but I am getting the same expression

When I try with $1$ as template,the value is not identified at all

Comment: I don't see any capturing group in your regex?

Comment: How should I add that group, Sorry I am not experienced in this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your response seems to be [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)
2. [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/4017) hence using regular expressions for parsing it is not the best idea

Consider switching to [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), the relevant configuration would be something like:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)

If you want to proceed with regular expressions for any reason consider changing your regular expression part from `[0-9]+` to `(\d+)`

Comment: Thank you. Changing to (\d+) solved the issue